# Evaluate variable without setting default value

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that measures the number of steps taken. I wanted to know, is it possible to set a value of 0 in the event that no steps are taken?

```
const Steps = this.props.steps;

this.data = {
      Activity: idExercise,
      FB: feedBack,
      Steps: Steps
}
```

So for example if the user tooks steps the value of this.props.steps will be equal to the sum of the steps (right and left foot). While if the user has not taken steps I would like to be equal to 0.

Can I use a ternary operator to evaluate this condition?

Comment: please share you conditions so that will esay to help you......

Comment: @abhikumar22 I have shared my conditions in the description of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ternary condition for this.
see here

```
this.data = {
      Activity: idExercise,
      FB: feedBack,
      Steps: this.props.steps ? this.props.steps : 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  OR operator  ||

```
const Steps = this.props.steps||0 //if steps = null return 0 instead
```

Then you can write
With the help of JS ES6

```
this.data = {
      Activity: idExercise,
      FB: feedBack,
      Steps
}
```

When the key and value are the same name